# Removing Yarmulka last when undressing (source)

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, clothing, kippa-yarmulka

I have noticed that some people remove their Yarmulka last when undressing 
and wear it first when dressing.

Is this custom mentioned anywhere?

Comment: It seems to me that there is a more general custom of dressing from top down and undressing from bottom up.  I have been looking for a source but haven't found one yet.

Comment: @BinyominTrager compare _Mishna B'rura_ 2:7 ("ואם סך כל גופו ראש תחלה מפני שהוא מלך על כל האיברים").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Shaalos U'Tshuvos Minchas Yitzchak 4:60](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1598&st=&pgnum=432), [Ben Ish Chai Parshas Vayishlach 1:17](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40322&st=&pgnum=40&hilite=), Halichos Shlomo 13:26, mention putting on the Yarmulke first when finishing to bathe. Halichos Shlomo also mentions leaving on the Yarmulke until all the clothing is removed.

> צרוך ללבוש הכיפה בראשונה מיד כשבא למקומו לפני כל מלבישיו ולסלקו מראשו
>   לאחר גמר פשיטת כל מלבושיו